# PyCharm will not perform a requests module update to the newest version

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, pycharm

I am having difficulty running a piece of requests code in my IDE PyCharm. The code is very basic and will work on my system for every website except one. Here is the code I am running:

```
import requests
initialURL = 'http://www.acastipharma.com/'
r = requests.get(initialURL)
```

When I run this code I get an error message that terminates with

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.acastipharma.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)'),))
```

I first thought this was an SSL problem, but if I run the requests command with the verify=False switch I still get the same error. This leads me to believe that the problem is not an SSL problem. I tried running the same code from a different IDE and the error did not occur which led me to believe the problem lies with my IDE PyCharm. I tried using a different project interpreter in PyCharm and the error also did not occur. I realized that the two different PyCharm project interpreters used different versions of requests and every PyCharm project interpreter I use that has the most recent version of requests the code will work but if the PyCharm project interpreter uses an older version of requests the error appears. Unfortunately PyCharm for some reason will not allow me to update the requests module in the PyCharm project interpreter I am using. Here is the error message I get from PyCharm when I attempt to update requests:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==2.19.1 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests==2.19.1
```

PyCharm then suggests that I run the upgrade command from terminal:

```
pip install -U requests==2.19.1
```

Here is what PyCharm suggests:

```
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5'.
```

When I run this from terminal I get this:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: requests==2.19.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (2.19.1)
```

It seems likely that the upgrade from terminal is occurring to the wrong directory, it is trying to update

```
./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

when I need it to update

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
```

Does anybody know how to specify the correct directory for the update when I run the pip install -U requests==2.19.1 command at terminal. Any assistance on how to get requests properly upgraded, whether from within PyCharm or at terminal, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was two-fold. The first problem was the version of OpenSSL that the project interpreter I was using was deprecated.  I also had two versions of Python 3.5 on my system and whenever I would attempt to update a package (ie. OpenSSL) the version of python that was not used by my project interpreter would update rather than the version of Python 3.5 I was using for the project interpreter. I ended up installing Python 3.7 and creating a project interpreter based on Python 3.7. By having only one version of 3.7 on my system I was able to update the OpenSSL package specifically associated with 3.7 and the problem went away.